# Kivy fails to mainApp.run()

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Today my Kivy app is suddenly no longer working with no change on my part... Might be due to the new version of Kivy breaking something? Any guess?

Here are the few lines of code seemingly causing the error:

```
class MemppApp(App):


    def build(self):        
        curdir = dirname(__file__)
        self.IDdisplayed=1
        mainDisplay = affichage( )
        return mainDisplay

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MemppApp().run() #here is the line 1308 it's complaining about...
```

It's the one line launching the main app.

Here is my output:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/vince/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-12-27_5.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) 
[GCC 9.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/usr/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.0.8'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [AudioGstplayer] Using Gstreamer 1.16.2.0
[INFO   ] [Audio       ] Providers: audio_gstplayer, audio_sdl2 (audio_ffpyplayer ignored)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/vince/Documents/programmes/Mempp/main.py", line 1308, in <module>
     MemppApp().run()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 949, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 918, in _run_prepare
     self.load_kv(filename=self.kv_file)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 691, in load_kv
     root = Builder.load_file(rfilename)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 306, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 404, in load_string
     widget = Factory.get(parser.root.name)(__no_builder=True)
   File "/home/vince/Documents/programmes/Mempp/main.py", line 1126, in __init__
     self.menu = Menu( self.configChange, self.searchPage)
   File "/home/vince/Documents/programmes/Mempp/main.py", line 719, in __init__
     self.sliders = slidersFreq()
   File "/home/vince/Documents/programmes/Mempp/main.py", line 777, in __init__
     self.loadSliders()
   File "/home/vince/Documents/programmes/Mempp/main.py", line 808, in loadSliders
     s = Slider( min=0,
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 350, in __init__
     super(Widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 245, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__
 TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error means you're passing an argument that a class doesn't expect/handle, so it gets passed on to the superclasses through `super`, and they pass it on in turn. When it reaches `object`, this error is thrown.

It isn't possible to be more specific because you haven't provided a minimal runnable example or the relevant code. Note that the traceback traces to code in your main.py that you have not posted here.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me even though my question wasn't detailed enough!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks inclement, it helped: the error was ideed due to this bit of code that I didn't put before:

```
s = Slider( min=0, max=100, value=Valeur, id = Clef)
```

I think it's because the id property is deprecated, as stated in Kivy 2.0.0 release notes:
https://github.com/kivy/kivy/releases/tag/2.0.0
(at "Breaking changes")

> [#6677]: Widget: Remove id from Widget.